# facing network error from react axios while running e2e tests in github actions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, next.js, github-actions

**Source Code Introduction**

We are using Github as our source repository and Github Actions to run the CI workflow to execute the e2e tests.
We have one source code inside that we are using puppeteer and Jest to run the e2e test cases and also running CI workflow to execute the same e2e test cases on PR request.
There are two other source codes one is for the backend (NodeJS) and one is for the frontend (React - NextJS) which will be used to run the e2e test cases.

**Problem we are facing**

The front end is not able to communicate with the backend - We are using Axios in React to call the backend endpoints.
in the Axios response we are always getting "Network Timeout error"

If we call the same endpoints using curl inside GitHub actions workflow it gives me the success output.

Below is the workflow file that we are using.

```
name:Tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      ref:
        required: true
      repo:
        required: true

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # container: node:latest
    services:
      # label used to access the service container
      postgres:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: postgres:latest
        # service environment variables
        # `POSTGRES_HOST` is `postgres`
        env:
          # optional (defaults to `postgres`)
          POSTGRES_DB: postgres_db
          # required
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres_password
          # optional (defaults to `5432`)
          POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
          # optional (defaults to `postgres`)
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres_user
        ports:
          # maps tcp port 5432 on service container to the host
          - 5432:5432
        # set health checks to wait until postgres has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
      redis:
        image: redis:6.2.6-alpine
        ports:
          - 6379:6379
    # strategy:
    #   matrix:
    #     node-version: [16.x]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout - API // Takes the checkout of backend 
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: node-backend
          token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.repo == 'backend' && github.event.inputs.ref || 'development' }}
      - name: Install Dependencies For API And Run API Server
        env:
          DB_HOST: localhost
          DB_DATABASE: postgres_db
          DB_USER: postgres_user
          DB_PASSWORD: postgres_password
          REDIS_HOST: localhost
          REDIS_PORT: 6379
          JWT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.JWT_SECRET }}
          JWT_EXPIRY_TIME: ${{ secrets.JWT_EXPIRY_TIME }}
          INTEGRATION_TEST_HOST_URL: http://localhost:3000
          MNEMONIC: ${{ secrets.MNEMONIC }}
          HUSKY: 0
          NODE_ENV: test
        run: |
          cd ../../
          mkdir backend
          cd backend
          cp -R ../e2e/e2e/* .
          npm i
          npm i -g pm2
          mkdir logs
          npm run sequelize db:migrate
          npm run sequelize db:seed:all
          npm run start&
      - name: Checkout - Web // Takes the checkout of frontend 
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: web
          token: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          ref: e2e-test-case-debugging
          # ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.repo == 'frontend' && github.event.inputs.ref || 'development' }}
      - name: Install Dependencies And Create Build For Web And Run Web Server
        run: |
          cd ../../
          mkdir web
          cd web
          cp -R ../e2e/e2e/* .
          cp ../e2e/e2e/.env.test .
          npm i
          npm i next@12.0.3 -g
          npm run build:local // build the frontend
          next start -p 3001& // start frontend on 3001
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Dependencies For Jest Puppeteer
        run: |
          curl 'http://localhost:3000/projects?&&sortBy=asc&'
          curl http://localhost:3000/contributor/prompt-submissions
          curl  'http://localhost:3000/co-creations?size=12&page=1&sortBy=desc&filterType=all'
          sudo apt update -y
          sudo apt install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget -y
          sudo apt install chromium-bsu -y
          npm i
      - name: test
        run: |
          npm run test
          curl 'http://localhost:3000/projects?&&sortBy=asc&'
          curl http://localhost:3000/contributor/prompt-submissions
          curl  'http://localhost:3000/co-creations?size=12&page=1&sortBy=desc&filterType=all'
      - name: Upload Video Files To Artifacts If Test Fails
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        if: ${{ failure() || success() }}
        with:
          name: video-files
          path: videos/
```

Let us know if we missing something here.

Thanks in Advance
Ronak